# Socket.io+AWS API gateway socket keeps on reconnecting and connect is never fired

Tags: socket.io, aws-api-gateway

AWS recently launched API gateway with sockets and it can proxy to lambda. In my observation AWS api socket is completely wss so I have done custom `connect` setting which is there in the code section. lambda and other setting I learned tested with wscat successfully as described in this link -
https://hackernoon.com/websockets-api-gateway-9d4aca493d39

But on integration with socket.io in browser it just keeps on reconnecting after 18-19 Seconds and connect is never fired! lambda and api gateway timeout is 30 Seconds which I think can be ignored as it doesn't interrupt the connection with wscat for 4-5 minutes.

I am new to sockets and the code in comments shows failed tries. Also tried googling but couldn't find much about AWS API socket and Socket.io. So any guidance or support is appreciated

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<script>
    socket = io(
        `wss://abcd.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod`
        , {
        path: `/prod/`,
        forceNew: true,
        // autoConnect: false,
        // reconnection: false,
        upgrade: true,
        transports: ['websocket',
        'polling',
        'flashsocket'
        ]
    });

    socket.on('connect', function () {
        socket.emit({"action":'message',"data":"hello return"}, () => {
          console.log("message Sent");
        });
  });

//         socket.emit({"action":'message',"data":"hello return"}, () => {
//           console.log("message"); // true
//         });
//         socket.on('message', () => {
//         console.log("message"); // true
//       });

//       socket.on("connection", function (socket) {
//     console.log("connection")
//   })

//       socket.on('connect', () => {
//       console.log("connect"); // true
//     });

//   socket.on('connected', () => {
//       console.log("connected"); // true
//     });

//     socket.on('open', () => {
//       console.log("open"); // true
//     });

//   socket.on('disconnect', (reason) => {
//    console.log("disconnect->",reason);
//    // if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
//     //   // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
//     //   socket.connect();
//     // }
//     // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
//   });

//   socket.on('close', (reason) => {
//    console.log("close->",reason);
//    // if (reason === 'io server disconnect') {
//     //   // the disconnection was initiated by the server, you need to reconnect manually
//     //   socket.connect();
//     // }
//     // else the socket will automatically try to reconnect
//   });

//   // socket.open();
//   // console.log(socket);

//   socket.on( (res) => {
//     console.log("res", res);
//   });



//   socket.on('reconnect', (attemptNumber) => {
//     console.log("reconnected", attemptNumber); // true
//   });

//   socket.on('reconnecting', (attemptNumber) => {
//     console.log("reconnecting...", attemptNumber); // true
//   });

//   socket.on('reconnect_error', (error) => {
//     console.log("reconnect_error",error);
//   });

//   socket.on('reconnect_attempt', (error) => {
//     console.log("reconnect_attempt->", error)
//     // socket.io.opts.transports = ['polling', 'websocket'];
//   });

//   socket.on('error', (error) => {
//     console.log("error->", error);
//   });



//   socket.on('ping', () => {
//     console.log("ping");
//   });

//   socket.on('pong', () => {
//     console.log("ping");
//   });


  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find anything?

Comment: Nope but trying hard. People aren't using AWS APIGateway much I think

Comment: One year now and no much doc. I gave up and replaced Socket.io with native WebSocket JS lib. The Socket.io doc says that they don't strictly follow WebSocket standards regarding headers (and no way to change them, according to them), so that could explain why the connection can't be established with AWS.

Comment: Good research @HansAraya Did you tried native WebSocket lib? It disconnects every 5 minutes in my case.

Comment: Yes, and sure it does. You would have to implement a keep-alive/ping-pong/heartbeat feature (like the one specified in https://github.com/websockets/ws#how-to-detect-and-close-broken-connections). I'm not sure if Socket.IO does it, but it probably does from behind.

Comment: Any updates can i use socket.io-client or ws library ? Can I get an example ?

Comment: @Jennings I have working code but without any socket library and it works with AWS api gateway web socket. I will post it here for you.

Comment: Any updates anybody on using socket.io with aws gateway? I am getting a 403 error when connection to api gateway when added a path /v1/socket.io , where v1 is the stage

Comment: @VishvendraSingh could you share your client code that uses antve websocket library? I tried implementing it, but can't get anything to work

Comment: @MrPablo I am so sorry I saw your comment very late, I will definitely share my code, but let me fist confirm if it is still working in production. I will update you soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested below Code in vue2 in Nuxt + Vuetify, I wanted to post for vue3 but I am still trying to get this done in little time I get after day Job. Any corrections are welcome. Thanks

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      socketconnection: {},
      listenersStarted: false,
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.onLoad()
    this.notificationDialog()
    this.startListeners()
    this.$on('serverSelected', (server) => {
      console.log('ran from $on server--', server)
      const message = {
        text: server,
        right: false,
        ts: new Date()
      }
      this.$store.commit('setMessage', message, { root: true })
    })
  },
  methods: {
    onLoad() {
      try {
        if (!localStorage.getItem('_t')) { return true }
        if (this.socketconnection === true) {
          console.log('socket already there... reconn unrequried!')
          return true
        }
        const token = localStorage.getItem('_t')
        const wsUri = `wss://test.example.com/prod?token=${token}`
        const websocket = new WebSocket(wsUri)
        websocket.onopen = (evt) => {
          this.socketconnection = true
        }
        websocket.onclose = (evt) => { this.onClose(evt) }
        websocket.onmessage = (evt) => { this.onMessage(evt) }
        websocket.onerror = (evt) => { this.onError(evt) }
      } catch (e) { console.log(e) }
    },
    onClose(evt) {
      this.socketconnection = false
      console.log('socket closed reconnecting...', evt)
      this.onLoad()
    },
    onMessage(evt) {
      console.log('evt---', evt)
      this.$emit('serverSelected', evt.data)
    },
    onError(evt) {
      console.log(evt)
    },
  }
}
```